# Vue state, cannot read property of null

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I used map state in computed to bring in the current state. My state data is displayed correctly in the template, but the console is logging an error saying data in the state is null. null is the initial value, but the state is set in a parent component.

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { settings } from '~/config'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      siteUrl: settings.siteUrl
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      fanpage: state => state.page.fanpage
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_header_photo' of null"
```

This is how I access the state of user_header_photo in the template

```
fanpage.user_header_photo
```

Comment: If you are fetching the `page` from an external api, there might be a delay due to server response. 

You can use `v-if="fanpage"` on your template to avoid this error.

Comment: that will do it. thanks!